# Is there any way to Restore a Database from newer version to an Older Version of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am having a database backup file from SQL SERVER 2012 and i wanted to restore it on SQL SERVER 2008R2 .
If we can’t restore a SQL Server 2012 database to earlier version what is the next best option?
So Is their any way to restore by any other way ??

Comment: You can't restore from a newer version of SQL to an older version. You will have to export your tables and import them into the older sql server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this would be possible would be to restore the Back up to a SQL 2012 instance and then try importing it to a SQL 2008-R2 instance. You may have to create some sort of ETL script to do the importing.